# Joomla 1.5 Chronoform v3 Email not being sent

Tags: joomla1.5, chronoforms

I've got a Joomla 1.5 (with Chronoform v3) website to edit. But I'm stuck with email sending. Even, from my mass-mail option, email is not being sent to the users, where I'm able to PM to only admin(myself).

For "Mailer: **PHP Mail Function**", I'm getting **"Could not instantiate mail function."**

For "Mailer: **SMTP Server**", the page, supposed to load after email sending, loads as a **blank page**.

For this real server-site, the global configs. till used are the following combinations:

Mailer: SMTP Server | PHP Mail Function | Sendmail
Mail From: admin@mydomain.com | my_gmail_username@gmail.com
From Name: Admin_LP
Sendmail Path: /usr/sbin/sendmail
SMTP Authentication: No | Yes
SMTP Security: None | TLS | SSL
SMTP Port: 25 | 26 | 465 | 587
SMTP Username: admin@ | @gmail.com
SMTP Password: ******  (respective email password)
SMTP Host: localhost | smtp.gmail.com

I've tried all possible combination found for the past 3 days and gone frustrated.

What should be the config. or what am I missing about sending mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my issue - the problem was with the hosting server! That server was Windows OS based which don't have PHP Mail Function activated and also the `php.ini` was not writable since it was a shared server.

So, I finally changed my server to a Linux based one, which also has `cPanel` facility. Now all are working as expected.